# What is the best way to revert to www version of domain name?

Tags: urls, options, site-url, google

My site uses a bare domain, example.com.

I want to use Google's Page Speed Service, which requires a www subdomain, like this www.example.com

Google says the server must use a 301 redirect.

What is the best way to do this? Can I simply change the WP General Settings and add the www there?

Comment: You need to apply `.htaccess` rules to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it at settings -> general, update Site address and wordpress address.

With my site wordpress automatically redirects the domain to www.